# When a edit is rejected, is a reason provided?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Reading this question

[Approve edits that only add a conclusion?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3938/approve-edits-that-only-add-a-conclusion)

I thought that if someone proposes an edit to a question and that edit is rejected after peer review, a reason for the rejection is provided. However, this didn’t happen in my case, so I guess providing a reason is not necessary. Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a list of all your suggested edits [in your profile under Activity > all actions > suggestions](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). Clicking on "rejected edit" will list the reject reasons for that edit. (Most of the time, reviewers will select a reason from the list. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239950/323179) for the complete list of reject reasons.)

In addition, the next time you try to suggest an edit, you will be [told](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137334/323179) that your previous edit was rejected. (Unfortunately, it's pretty easy to [miss the banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304023/323179). You do not get any inbox notifications either for rejected edits.)

---

If you're referring to [this edit](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/30186), I was one of the reviewers that rejected it. My reasoning is: the answerer should be in charge of what sources they use because any downvotes on the post will affect their reputation if the source is problematic. If you think including the source will help the answer, you can leave a comment and let the answerer decide if they will include it or not.

(Note that the post owner will be notified of all suggested edits on their post. The post owner can single-handedly decide if the edit should be approved or rejected, [even if it means overturning the decision made by reviewers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295028/323179).)

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. I 100% agree that leaving a comment, instead than single-handedly proposing an edit, is the best thing to do, and this is what I always do on the other communities to which I participate regularly. However, I took a different approach this time, because user @Sklivvz deleted my comments, and he told me that "an edit would be much more appropriate!" https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4152/44125. So...should I propose edits or leaving comments? I'm getting conflicting inputs here.

Comment: For what it concerns the source: the American Journal of Public Health is, like, one of the best journals in its field. It's ranked 12th worldwide http://www.scimagojr.com/journalrank.php?category=2739 and 6th among the american journals on Public Health, Environmental and Occupational Health. The paper I chose is from 2013 (thus, relatively recent), has 88 citations and it's from widely respected researchers in the field. Given that there are two amendments which seriously restrict US government to fund or publish gun violence research, I don't see how you could get a better source than this.

Comment: Having said that, I reiterate that I 100% agree with you when you say that the answerer **must** be in charge of the sources. I'm firmly convinced that my source is reliable, but of course this is not my answer, and the respondent is the only one who gets to decide what's reliable and what is not. You are completely right, and I understand the rejection. My goal was only to help an excellent question keep its excellency, after user @Brythan decided to remove the yellow plot (for which I provided sources), by substituting that plot with unassailable sources, but it didn't work out. I get it.

Comment: Just one last comment. The intent of the edit was not " to address the author of the post". The point was that user @Brythan removed the Mother Jones plot (which the respondent has initially included in his answer) with the motivation "Removed comparison of all gun deaths, including suicides, to gun owner". I then thought that adding a comparison of gun deaths **only by homicide** to gun ownership, from a source which is widely regarded as reliable, would restore the OP original intent. This was the motivation of my edit.

Comment: Done commenting the original answer, as you suggested. Thanks again for your enlightening answer.

Answer (score 2):

If someone has their edit rejected, does a notification appear in their inbox? Does that notification include the reasons?

Good questions, but I don't know the answers, sorry. I have no recollection.

However, I can say that if you look in the post's edit history, you can see the suggestion and the rejection reasons.

Here is [the edit I believe you are referring to](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/30186), including who reviewed it and which option they selected.

Comment: thanks, I get it now.